# Program calculating tax rate per line item equalling into BTW

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df:

```
     quantity#1    unit price#1    line amount#1    line amount#2    line amount#3    line amount#4    BTW
--  ------------  --------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  -----
 0           nan           nan                  5              nan              nan              nan   1.05
 2             1          1150.5               10               20               30              nan   6.6
 6             1          2458               2458              nan              nan              nan   0
13             1          1689                 10               20               30              nan   5.4
17             1           260                260               30              100               75  73.05
```

From this DF, I want to extract the tax rate from the specific line rates. The tax rates can be 0.09, 0.21 and 0.00 and equal into the BTW subset.
I've tried the following:

```
x = [0.09, 0.21, 0.00]

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Document Type'] == 0:
        df['line amount'[i]] * x == df['BTW']
```

however this does not work..

Desired output:

```
     quantity#1    unit price#1    line amount#1    line amount#2    line amount#3    line amount#4    BTW 
--  ------------  --------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  -----
 0           nan           nan                  5              nan              nan              nan   1.05
 2             1          1150.5               10               20               30              nan   6.6
 6             1          2458               2458              nan              nan              nan   0
13             1          1689                 10               20               30              nan   5.4
17             1           260                260               30              100               75  73.05

tax rate line amount #1 
0.21
```

for each line amount the tax rate which equals into the BTW column

Please help

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to multiply each line amount by 0.09, 0.21 and 0.00? What does BTW stand for?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite this line

```
df['line amount'[i]] * x == df['BTW']
```

to

```
df['line amount'[i]] = df['BTW'] * x
```